# Chrome reports false warning downloading .zip file

Tags: google-chrome, website

We recently launch a site that allows user to create apps and download them (.zip file) to their computer before running them. However, Chrome always gives warning that the file is "not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous" although it is not. I even check the Google safe search and Google confirms that the site is "not malicious".

Is there anything that can be done to fix the issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested this from different machines at different locations? Make sure this is not a setting specific to the system you test from.

Comment: Does the zip file contain .EXEs? If so, I think it is fair that Chrome warns that the file is "not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous" and so you could probably place a note on the download page assuring your site's users that Chrome will show a warning and it is still ok to download.

Comment: It happens to my site and my software too. It looks like they have a default blocking policy.